# SQLAdapter in MobileFirstPaltform giving error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am calling SQLAdapter from below adapter:

```
function callFetchBalance(msisdn, circle,imei) {
    try {
        var response = WL.Server.invokeProcedure({
            adapter : "sqladapter",
            procedure : "checkIMEIAndMSISDN",
            parameters : [ msisdn,imei ]
        });
        if(response.isSuccessful){
            if(typeof response.resultSet[0]!== 'undefined' && null!=response.resultSet[0]) {
                var count = response.resultSet[0].COUNT;
                if(count!='1.0'){
                    return {
                        exception_code : "403"
                    }
                }else{
                    var callMethod = new com.actions.Util();
                    var balanceReturned = callMethod.getBalance(msisdn, circle);
                    return {
                        balance : balanceReturned
                    };
                }
            }else{
                return {
                    balance : "null"
                };
            }
        }else{
            return {
                balance : "null"
            };
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            balance : "null"
        };
    }
}
```

And my adapter is like this:

```
var checkIMEIAndMSISDN = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select count(*) as count from AUTH_TABLE where MSISDN=? and IMEI=?");
function checkIMEIAndMSISDN(msisdn,imei) {
    var response =  WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : checkIMEIAndMSISDN,
        parameters : [msisdn,imei]
    });

    return response;
}
```

But on running this, I am getting below error:

```
    [8/21/17 17:42:29:036 IST] 000000be DataAccessSer E  logError FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project UtilApp]sqladapter/checkIMEIAndMSISDNFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project UtilApp]
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject incompatible with org.mozilla.javascript.Function
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project UtilApp]nulljava.lang.ClassCastException: org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject incompatible with org.mozilla.javascript.Function
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.getFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:260)
```

Also from the log, it is showing caused from below line:

```
var response = WL.Server.invokeProcedure({
```

Someone please suggest me whats wrong in this line or I am getting this error due to some other code.

Comment: Do you get the same error when the if(response.isSuccessful){ .. } is removed?

Comment: What version of MobileFirst are you using?
It looks like you're trying to invoke the SQLAdapter from a different adapter?  Is that correct?

Comment: I am using MFP 7.0. I resolved this problem by renaming var checkIMEIAndMSISDN to some other string. Actually my method name was also the same.